# "For" loop better alternative

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

Having too many many "For" loop in my code increase complexity to my development, is there a better solution to For loop alternative?

In my code. I have used 50% of the time to loop array.

Comment: You should show some concrete code to get a better idea of what is that you are doing. Are you iterating over data structures? are you using the for loops to find elements specific elements or to modify all items in an array? etc...

Comment: Yes, reading musical properties in array, each notes has 10 properties which mean 10 arrays. Will have to compare values and these are simply hard than building 3D game. Feel like mental drain already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have to work on Arrays alot check the [reference](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/) under Array. They have very usefull functions like Array.every() or Array.forEach() or Array.map().

Maybe one of those is helpful to your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's `for each` and `while`, but they're still loops!

Sometimes, looping is just necessary, and there's no way around it.  Can you explain more about what you think is wrong with your current code, or perhaps post a code sample?

On the contrary, if you use the same loop style throughout the application, it *may* make it easier to read for third parties.

Comment: I prefer while. Much faster than for when you work with larger arrays.

Comment: @heartcode and while prevents you from having to type in for(var i: int = 0;... which I always seem to type wrong the first time! :)

Comment: Well, I am developing a Musical Notes app like Finale or Sibelius that will display notes on Treble and Bass, especially Orchestra score, have to align them in correct position. So like using too many array to check positions, type of notes, chords, accidental, etc. It's seem overload, haha.